# App rejected by google play store due to google permission Policy

Tags: android, google-play-services

Our app is still rejected due following reasons.

```
Based on our review, we found your app’s expressed user experience 
did not match your declared core functionality Default SMS handler (and 
any other core functionality usage while default handler). Please 
remove these permissions from your app.

Default handler capability was listed on your declaration form, but 
your app does not appear to have default handler capability. Please 
submit a revised declaration form.

Your app needs to use runtime permissions for us to complete the 
review. Please update your app to target API level 26 or above. If you 
have APKs in different tracks of the app releases section of your Play 
Console, please deactivate non-compliant APKs before submitting your 
app again. For additional guidance, please review the documentation on 
how to request app permissions
```

We are not using any permissions Which are included in Default SMS Handler.

We do not have any APKs on Other track.

Our target Api version is 28, but rejection mail says that it should be 26 or above.

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

Comment: What does your manifest look like?

Comment: i have edited the question.Check the mainfest permissions

Comment: As far as I understand, you told Google your app wants to be default sms app, but it actually does not have such capability. Don't declare permissions you don't mean to use

Comment: sms permission are use by external libraries like PayU Intent Sdk and facebook sdk to remove it we used " tools:node="remove" "

Comment: what is your taget level api ? what is the use for sms permission? Did you ask a sms permission in run time?

Answer (score 3):

This is how we resolved the issue.

**What was the Issue:**

App was getting rejected every time we upload new APK to Production
even thought it was not using any SMS related permissions.

**Cause:**

There was very old APK in Beta release track.
This had SMS related permissions.

**Why we couldn't resolve it earlier:**

Beta track was not visible in Google Play Console,
because there was APK in Alpha (Open Testing track).
(Only Alpha or Beta can run as Open Testing track at a time).

**Solution:**

1. We changed Alpha track to Closed testing track.
2. Uploaded latest APK in all tracks (Internal Testing, Beta and Production).

AND Bingo!!

The app is LIVE Now!!

**References:**

https://proandroiddev.com/dear-googles-permissions-declaration-form-can-we-break-up-85bc6b62f690

[Playstore prompts to 'Declare sensitive permissions'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54398534/playstore-prompts-to-declare-sensitive-permissions)

[Receive_SMS Permission issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707033/receive-sms-permission-issue)